# Effects of gravity on light on the surface of the Earth

Tags: gravity, visible-light, photons

I read over the question and answers on the effects of gravity on light.  I would like to ask a more specific question about gravity and light.

**What is the effect of gravity on light on the surface of the earth?**

Comment: Youll have to be way more specific though. What do you want to know about? (note: *effect$\neq$ affect*)

Comment: This question is too broad and demonstrates that you don't have the background to to make the discussion productive. If you are interested, read the background necessary to understand the question you are asking. In a nutshell, the effect of gravity on light on the surface of the earth is negligible. Physics is best understood when looking at the limits of theories. Instead look at how light propagates without a gravitational field and then in the presence of a singularity (black hole). You will need an understanding of relativistic quantum field theory as a basis for this question.

Comment: It is the same as anywhere... the mass of the earth affects the curvature of spacetime; light travels in a "straight" line in this curved spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the effect of gravity on light on the surface of the earth?

It bends it downwards. Just a little. Pick up a pencil, and drop it onto your desk. Let's say it falls half a metre and takes [0.32 seconds](http://www.angio.net/personal/climb/speed).

Now imagine a light beam moving from left to right. If that light beam was travelling from left to right for the same time as your pencil was falling down, it would curve downwards by 1m. The deflection of light is twice the Newtonian deflection of matter, see Ned Wright's [deflection and delay article](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/deflection-delay.html) for a bit about that. Of course, the light would have to be moving from left to right for circa 96,000 kilometres and the Earth just isn't that big. But this should be enough to give you the idea.